# Regex: Symbol exactly once in string

Tags: regex

I am struggling with a regular expression for detecting if a special character (hashtag **#**) is included exactly once in a string. Everything before and after the hashtag is unknown and can be any symbol (including whitespace and special characters).

**Examples:**

`#` matches

`##` doesnt match

`a12bc#1def65` matches

`a12bc##1def65` doesnt match

`a234341#1212` matches

`a23$. 4341#1 ._21&2` matches

`#a23$. 4341#1 ._21&2#` doesnt match

I think that would be quiet simple (I am not really good in regex) so I tried

`#{1}`

Surprisingly this does not work as I expected. This regex matches also the string `##`.
Then I tried some stuff like `#{1}\b` and `(#{1}\b|[^#{2}])`. But everytime either the string `#` dont match or `##` do match the regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern `#{1}\b` can be written as `#\b` and matches `#` only if followed by a word boundary. This does not take a number of occurrences into account for a whole line.

This pattern `(#{1}\b|[^#{2}])` has the same as before, followed by an alternation `|` and [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^#{2}]` that can  match a single char other than chars `#` `{` `2` `}`

---

If you don't want to match newlines, and match the whole string:

```
^[^\r\n#]*#[^\r\n#]*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\r\n#]*` Optionally match any char except a newline or `#`
- `#` Match the `#` char
- `[^\r\n#]*` Optionally match any char except a newline or `#`
- `$` End of string

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oDQKS2/1)

Comment: Thanks that works. Maybe it was my fault to write separate lines in rege101.